# Python filename change

Tags: python, macos

I have a number of videos in a directory on my Mac that all have a specific string in the file name that I want to remove, but I want to keep the rest of the file name as it is. I'm running this python script from terminal.

I have this syntax but it doesn't seem to work.  Is it practical to use the following?  It seems to simple to be the best way to do this sort of thing which is why I don't think it works.

```
from os import rename, listdir

text = "Some text I want to remove from file name"
files = listdir("/Users/Admin/Desktop/Dir_of_videos/")

for x in files:
    if text in files:
        os.rename(files, files.replace(text, ""))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you get incomplete paths when you are using `listdir`, basically, it returns only the files in the directory without the prepending path to the directory

this should do the job:

```
import os

in_dir = './test'
remove = 'hello'

paths = [os.path.join(in_dir,file) for file in os.listdir(in_dir) if remove in file]

for file in paths:
    os.rename(file, file.replace(remove, ""))
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  Thanks :)  Can you explain "file"?  Is it literally telling the script use this "file"?

Comment: `file` is just and iterator here, e.g., when I am doing `os.listdir('./test')`, `file` would be e.g., 'planet.png', or 'world.png'

Comment: You can insert a `print(paths)` to see how the paths looks like and compare them to `os.listdir('./test')`

Comment: PS: thanks for the idea. I started to collect such little things in form of command line tools for re-usability: https://github.com/rasbt/py-args